# .NET Core passing a single property to a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project using Razor Pages, I have the following page model:

```
[BindProperty]
public AddUserPageModel Input { get; set; }

public class AddUserPageModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> ImageUploads { get; set; }
}
```

From this Razor Page View, I insert a partial view and pass the model which is a single property:

```
<partial name="Partials/_AddPhotos" model="@Model.Input.ImageUploads" />
```

And in the Partial View:

```
@model List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile>

<input asp-for="@Model" type="file" multiple>
```

Which results in the following error:

`System.ArgumentException: The name of an HTML field cannot be null or empty.`

So it seems the issue is in the partial view, that `asp-for="@Model"` needs a `.PropertyName` but I'm not sure how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass `@Model.Input` to your partial view.

And use AddUserPageModel as the page model in your partial view.

```
@model Project.Models.AddUserPageModel

<input asp-for="@Model.ImageUploads" type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: This does indeed work, but it feels like s bit of a hack.

Comment: asp-for attribute adds an id and a name based on the property name. The model seems can not be a single type.